Error : Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact
I wanted to deploy my project on nexus i have checked all but this error keeps appearing when using 'mvn deploy' on my project : Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact tn.esprit.spring:gestion-station-ski:jar:1.0 from/to Devops (http://192.168.33.10:8081/repository/maven-releases/): authentication failed for http://192.168.33.10:8081/repository/maven-releases/tn/esprit/spring/gestion-station-ski/1.0/gestion-station-ski-1.0.jar, status: 401 Unauthorized
this is the configuration on pom.xml :
pom.xml
this is settings.xml :
settings.xml
Any help ?
i tried to modify password and change it on settings.xml but it didn't help.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. Instead, [edit] your question to include the code as properly formatted text.

Check that the username and password works. Also, check that the user has the necessary permissions.
